# How to use IntentFliter for URL to get every link?

Tags: android, url, android-intent

I am trying to set up a filter for URLs specific to my domain and a certain subdomain. This is what I have so far:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
    <data android:scheme="https" android:host="www.mywebsite.com" android:pathPattern="/mysubdir/id=*"/>
</intent-filter>
```

I tried it without the host (only pathPattern), with and without the first slash on pathPattern and every combination I thought of, but it always links my app to every https link I click. What is going on here?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

I realised that I should be using `pathPattern=/mysubdir/id=.*` , but even after this change, nothing happens.

Comment: Maybe `android:host="mywebsite.com"`?

Comment: The answer might be here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958701/launch-custom-android-application-from-android-browser

Comment: Have you tried `android:pathPrefix="/mysubdir/id="` instead of `pathPattern`?

Comment: Just tried with android:pathPrefix="/mysubdir/id=", android:pathPrefix="/mysubdir/id=*", android:pathPrefix="mysubdir/id=", android:pathPrefix="mysubdir/id=*" and the result is always the same. It's as if scheme is overriding everything there.

Comment: @RostislavPashuto : thanks for the link, but my problem is not that I'm not getting my app to launch. The problem is that it's launching too much.